# How to change an image that is inside a link on a hover

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve, is when the image hovered it will change to another. But I guess that the anchor tag is preventing that. How to do so without using any event handler for the image tag. Thanks.

Consider the following code:

```css
#imgId:hover {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000");
}
```

```html
<a href=""><img id="imgId" width="40" height="40" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't do that with `img` tag, but you can try to replace it with `div` tag instead with the use of `background-image`, sample here:

```css
#imgId {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/200'), url('https://placekitten.com/256/256');
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover #imgId {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/256/256');
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com"><div id="imgId"></div></a>
```

(The additional `background-image` in the non-hover state is just to pre-load the image to prevent flickering, as requested by the requester)

Comment: Thank @AngYC, useful technique, but I am trying to use it with only the img tag, so that I can set my width an height there. You should know that setting the width and height the way you do may push the web page to flicker.

Comment: Hi @Learning, I am not quite sure what you mean by flicker, do you mean it will turn white when the image is loading? If so, it is intended, but I have modified the code to pre-load the image in the background first

Comment: The browser asks for the html content from the server without the resources like images. So if you use <img src="someSource"> and set the width using css, the browser will not create the dimensions of the image, but when it loads it from the server, it will create the dimension in a way your web page will look like it increasing size, that's flickering. To avoid that it is better to write <img src="someSource" width="some width" height="some height">. But I could be wrong

Comment: Hi @Learning, yes you are right about the flickering (we call it Layout shifting)! However, when used in `background-image`, the element will not be resized. In addition, you can also set the size of it by passing as a inline-CSS like so: `<div id="imgId" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">`

Comment: Well thanks for the tip @AngYC ))

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather keep the image element you can use an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element as an overlay. Note that I moved the ID to the anchor for this because images don't have pseudo-elements.

```css
#imgId {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#imgId:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000");
}
```

```html
<a id="imgId" href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just try doing it with `img` tag.

```css
img
{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
img:hover
{
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000");
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with padding to hide the original image:

```css
#imgId {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* this is important */
  /* you can define the image here */
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100/ff0000");
}
/* update only the padding on hover */
#imgId:hover {
  padding: 50px; /* half the width */
}
```

```html
<a href=""><img id="imgId" width="40" height="40" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"></a>
```